# Algorithmic trading strategies for financial derivatives

Tags: derivatives, algorithmic-trading

are there any strategies or considerations specifically designed for the algorithmic trading of financial derivatives, or textbooks that focus on this topic rather than underlying equities and traditional asset classes?